List comprehension to return list if value is non-existent
I'm aiming to use list comprehension to return values in a list. Specifically, if 'x' is in a list, I want to drop all other values. However, if 'x' is not in the list, I want to return the same values (not return an empty list).
list1 = ['d','x','c']
list2 = ['d','b','c']

list1 = [s for s in list1 if s == 'x']
list2 = [s for s in list2 if s == 'x']

List2 would return []. Where I want it to be ['d','b','c']
list2 = [s for s in list2 if s == 'x' else list2]

Returns:
list2 = [s for s in list2 if s == 'x' else list2]
                                      ^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


list2 = [s for s in list2 if s == 'x'] if 'x' in list2 else list2

"Specifically, if 'x' is in a list, I want to drop all other values. However, if 'x' is not in the list, I want to return the same values (not return an empty list)." A list comprehension does a single pass, one element at a time. By the time we know 'x' isn't in the list, we have already looked at all the elements (to make sure they aren't 'x'), so it's impossible for the comprehension to go back and include them.

This would keep all elements that aren't x
list2 = [x for x in list2 if x != 'x']

However, if x is in the list, it'll still return all other elements.
So, you'd need two passes to check whether x does exist since list comprehension alone cannot return that information
def filter_x(lst):
  if 'x' in lst:
    return [x for x in lst if x == 'x']
  else:
    return lst


Yeh ok. Thought it might come to this but wasn't sure. Really then, it could be if 'x' in lst: lst = ['x'] else: lst = lst

Not if the list has more than one x

How about:
list1 = [s for s in list1 if s == 'x'] or list1

If the comprehension produces an empty list, the or operator will treat it as False and return the complete list.

Not that it matters a lot, but you can do this more efficiently. if 'x' in lst will traverse the list once, and then you have to rebuild the list again. Instead, just assume x is in the list and build your list of x's:
tmp = [x for x in lst if x == 'x']

then, check if there is an element in this list. If yes, use it, otherwise set it to the original list:
tmp = tmp if len(tmp) > 0 else lst

Of course, this depends on your use case/if you need a copy (so that you cannot mutate the original list). If your plan was to overwrite the original list, then change that second line for:
lst = tmp if len(tmp) > 0 else lst

This is just the difference between traversing the list twice versus once.

if len(tmp) > 0 can just be if tmp

@juanpa.arrivillaga you're correct, and I think the PEPs say do that, but I am in the camp of "I disagree". In a strongly typed language it would make sense, but I don't like it in Python for readability purposes.
